# Arduino: Delay of 1ms necessary between Serial.read and Serial.write?

Tags: arduino, atmega, delay

We have a [Razor IMU (10736)](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736) sensor board connected to a [RS-485 Breakout](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10124) board, talking RS485 to the computer via a [USB-RS485 Serial Interface](http://www.robotshop.com/ca/productinfo.aspx?pc=RB-Dev-25). We use the [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/) to program Razor's on-board ATmega328 (code is based on the [Razor AHRS](https://dev.qu.tu-berlin.de/projects/sf-razor-9dof-ahrs) open source firmware).

Everything works fine, but for one detail: The Arduino-programmed Razor seems to need a small delay between the reading-in and the writing-out of a serial message. The way it works, is: the computer polls the razor, the razor reads the request and then responds by reporting it's data. The code looks like this (simplified) :

```
if(Serial.available() > 0) {

  int incoming = (int) Serial.read();    // read data
  delay(1);                              // ??? why necessary ???
  digitalWrite(RTS_PIN, HIGH);           // RE high, sets RS485-board to transmit
  Serial.write(c);                       // send data
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(RTS_PIN, LOW);            // RE low, sets RS485-board to receive

}
```

There is the need for a delay of minimum 1 millisecond between executing Serial.read() and any form of output (digitalWrite and/or Serial.write()). We tried setting the value lower into the microseconds range, but always got corrupted data packages as a result. This problem does not occur when you only poll the razor once in a while, but when you repeatedly poll it at short time intervals (the computer waits for a response and then automatically triggers a new polling). This all is happening at a baud rate of 76800 right now.

Next we did tests by programming the Razor's on-board ATmega328 directly with C code. And this eliminated the need for the delay value! Reading and writing serial data could happen right after each other. But - as we'd like to stay within the Arduino language (for several reasons) - we'd like to figure how we could solve this problem in other ways.

In the Arduino firmware, the Serial library, is there any reason why there would have to be a delay of 1ms between Serial input and Serial output? And if yes, are there ways of changing that?

Comment: Can you look at the signals on an oscilloscope to ensure they are actually the exact baud rate you have the serial port configured for?

Comment: Not at the moment. But i did try with different baud rates (9600, 57600, 76800) and the problem seemed consistent.

Comment: Was the fix of directly coding in C also consistent across baud rates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by programming with an older version of the Arduino IDE (i used Arduino 0022). Apparently Arduino 1.0 has a different buffered writes queuing system. See the [answers on the Arduino](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,98471.msg739885.html#msg739885) forum for more information.